# python: getting value from a dictionary and inserting it into another dictionary as key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to print it out where each key represents the company name, and the value represents the number of videos launched, like the following example:
{"Grab": 1, "Uber": 3}

but I can get the correct value. please advice. thanks!

```
video_ads = [
{"title": "Healthy Living", "company": "Uber", "views": 15934, "created_days_ago": 302, "bounce_rate": 0.17},
{"title": "Get a ride, anytime anywhere", "company": "Uber", "views": 923834, "created_days_ago": 289, "bounce_rate": 0.11},
{"title": "Send money to your friends with GrabPay", "company": "Grab", "views": 23466, "created_days_ago": 276, "bounce_rate": 0.08},
{"title": "Ubereats now delivers nationwide", "company": "Uber", "views": 1337, "created_days_ago": 270, "bounce_rate": 0.04}
]


industry_data = {}
videos_count = 0

for key in video_ads:
    print(key["company"])
    company = key["company"]

if company in industry_data:
    videos_count += 1

else:
    industry_data[company] = videos_count
    videos_count += 1

print(industry_data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the way you accumulate you data. It should be done in the for loop. You don't need an extra `video_count`. Just sum them up in  `industry_data` like so:

```
industry_data = {}

for key in video_ads:
    company = key["company"]

    if company in industry_data:
        industry_data[company] += 1
    else:
        industry_data[company] = 1

print(industry_data)
# {'Uber': 3, 'Grab': 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **`collections.Counter`**:

```
from collections import Counter

video_ads = [
{"title": "Healthy Living", "company": "Uber", "views": 15934, "created_days_ago": 302, "bounce_rate": 0.17},
{"title": "Get a ride, anytime anywhere", "company": "Uber", "views": 923834, "created_days_ago": 289, "bounce_rate": 0.11},
{"title": "Send money to your friends with GrabPay", "company": "Grab", "views": 23466, "created_days_ago": 276, "bounce_rate": 0.08},
{"title": "Ubereats now delivers nationwide", "company": "Uber", "views": 1337, "created_days_ago": 270, "bounce_rate": 0.04}
]

c = Counter(x['company'] for x in video_ads)

print(c)
# Counter({'Uber': 3, 'Grab': 1})
```

Comment: instead of just writing a different solution, it would be nice if you could point to the error in the ops code / reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

```
result_dict = {}
for k in video_ads:
    try:
        result_dict[k['company']] += 1
    except KeyError:
        result_dict[k['company']] = 1

print (result_dict)
#{'Uber': 3, 'Grab': 1}
```

Comment: Or `result_dict[k['company']] = result_dict.get(k['company'], 0) + 1`

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it correct. The if loop should be inside the for loop with some minor modification as below:

```
industry_data = {}
videos_count = 0

for key in video_ads:
    print(key["company"])
    company = key["company"]
    if company not in industry_data:
        industry_data[company] = 1
    else:
        industry_data[company] += 1

print(industry_data)
```